# separating dictionary values from inside of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

> So currently I am working on extracting data from who.is, there were about 2000 links so I simply iterated over it with the function, but output is some what like this:

```
[{"email":"email@email.com", "Phone_no.":"+123456789", "more data":"more data", "even more data":"even more data"},
{"email":"email@email.com", "Phone_no.":"+123456789", "more data":"more data", "even more data":"even more data"},
{"email":"email@email.com", "Phone_no.":"+123456789", "more data":"more data", "even more data":"even more data"}]
```

> the desired output is somewhat like:

```
["email@email.com","email@email.com","email@email.com"],["+123456789","+123456789","+123456789"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate on each dictionnary of your list.

That will look like somthething like this :

```
email = []
phone_no = []

for d in data:
   for key,value in d:
      if(str(key) == 'email'):
         email.append(value)
      elif(str(key) == 'Phone_no.'):
         phone_no.append(value)
      else:
         pass
```

So you have the email list with all email adresses and phone_no with all phone numbers

Comment: probably you want to edit the key to be `'Phone_no.'` with capital P.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a variable called `data`:

```py
emails = [d['email'] for d in data]
phone_numbers = [d['Phone_no.'] for d in data]

print(emails)
print(phone_numbers)
```

Output:

```
['email@email.com', 'email@email.com', 'email@email.com']
['+123456789', '+123456789', '+123456789']
```